# How to get the result csv file in between the test run during performance testing using Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am using Jmeter Version 4. For example I am running test for four hours, And during the test run, I want the result file for the test ran from 2nd to 3rd hour.Is it possible to get the result file like that?
I know that we can get the result file from starting to 3rd hour.But I want from 2nd to 3rd hour.
Can I get that.Please suggest?

Comment: I am running the test in NON _ GUI mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest option is going for [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/) which has `--start-offset` and `--end-offset` parameters specifying how to "cut" the original .jtl file (in seconds) so you could do something like:

```
FilterResults --output-file from2ndto3rd_hour.jtl --input-file /path/to/large/result.jtl --start-offset 7200 --end-offset 10800
```

Filter Results Tool can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager):

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dmriti, I am facing NoClassDefFound error when I try to merge.Should I add any extra fields in the output result file.Because to filter based on offset I dont find any values in output file generated at the end of test run,

Comment: Which exact class is not found?

Comment: ERROR: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jmeterplugins/save/MergeResultsService

Comment: It appears you need to install [Merge Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) as well

Comment: Yes.We could see merging is happening now

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should use this solution that allows you to have live results:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html

But if you want to work with CSV, your best bet would be to modify the timestamp format by adding to **user.properties** :

> jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=yyyyMMddHHmmss

And ensure JMeter flushes on every write to avoid having partial lines:

> jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true

And then use grep, for example to take results between 15 and 16h on 26 january 2019

> grep "2019012615" results.csv > filter.csv

If you don't want to rely on grep, then you can take the whole file and generate the HTML report using :

> jmeter -Jjmeter.reportgenerator.start_date=20190126150000 -Jjmeter.reportgenerator.end_date=20190126160000  -g results.csv -o reportfolder